# One To Many (1-N) relation in Laravel backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using [Laravel BackPack CRUD](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD). I have a 1-N (One To Many) relation between two tables :

- a **personne** belongs to one **structure**
- in a **structure** there is many **personnes**

So i have a **personnes** table :

idPersonnes, name, firstname, idStructures

And a **structure** table :

idStructures, name, adress

In my personne Model i have :

```
public function structure()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Structure', 'idStructures', 'idStructures');
}
```

In my personne controller i have :

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'label' => 'Structure',
            'type' => 'select2',
            'name' => 'idStructures', // the db column for the foreign key
            'entity' => 'structure', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'attribute' => 'nom', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
            'model' => 'App\Models\Structure' // foreign key model
        ]);
```

This is working well. I have select2 dropdown when i edit a personne and i can choose and save a structure.

Now when i edit a structure i want to show all the personnes that belongs to that structure.
In my structure model i have :

```
public function personnes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Personne', 'idStructures', 'idStructures');
}
```

In my structure controller i have :

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'label' => 'Personnes',
            'type' => 'select2',
            'name' => 'idStructures', // the db column for the foreign key
            'entity' => 'personnes', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'attribute' => 'nom', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
            'model' => 'App\Models\Personne' // foreign key model
        ]);
```

It's not working.
Am i doing something wrong ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Same question & answer here: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/339

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should use

```
select2_multiple
```

in this case.

```
$this->crud->addField([
                'label' => 'Personnes',
                'type' => 'select2_multiple',
                'name' => 'idStructures', // the db column for the foreign key
                'entity' => 'personnes',
                'attribute' => 'nom', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
                'model' => 'App\Models\Personne' // foreign key model
        ]);
```

Let me know if this helped